# VTD-XML can't vn.getText() if text has HTML <B> tags?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

The XML looks like this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="SignInPrompt">Sign in with <b>%1$s</b></string>
</resources>
```

navigation looks like this:

```
if (vnCurrent.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "string")) {
while (true) {
    def currentStringIndex = vnCurrent.getText()
    // ^^^^ this is always -1 when it hits the strings with <B>
    def currentStringValue = (currentStringIndex != -1) ? vnCurrent.toRawString(currentStringIndex) : ""

    if (!vnCurrent.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING)) break
}
```

I'm trying to grab the XML text to do processing on it.
We don't encode the

```
<B> as &lt;B&gt;
```

because Android understands how to convert the bolded string properly when reading the string from resources w/o going through a separate fromHtml call.

Comment: if you don't encode <B> as &lt;B&gt;, then your xml won't be well formed, right?